# How to use OAuth2 with node.js

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to use @google-cloud client lib to insert data to BigQuery.
Since I have multiple clients and each has different IAM role I can't use a service account like this:

```
const bigquery = new BigQuery({
                projectId: `myProject`,
                keyFilename: '/Users/services/ssh/myProject-111.json'
            });
```

rather I would like to use client-specific oauth2 like this:

```
const bigquery = new BigQuery({
                projectId: `mydata-1470162410749`,
                token: clientOauth2Token
            });
```

I get this error

> Error in the process: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. - Invalid Credentials

This is the full mocha test code I'm using:

```
import BigQuery from '@google-cloud/bigquery';
import {GoogApi} from "../apiManager" //Private code to get Token from client DB

if (!global._babelPolyfill) {
    var a = require("babel-polyfill")
}

describe('Check routing', async () => {

    it('Test stack  ', async (done) => {

        //Fetch client Auth from local Database
        let apiManager = new GoogApi({query: {integrationTest: 'on'}}, {}, (err, httpResults) => {});
        let clientAuth = await apiManager.getGoogleTokensByUserId(`user@company.con`);

        //Replace the 2 value below with real values
        const tableName = "myTest";
        const dataset = "EVALUEX_DEV";

        try {
            const bigquery = new BigQuery({
                projectId: `myProject`,
                token: clientAuth.credentials.access_token
            });
            await bigquery.createDataset(dataset)
                .then(
                    args => {
                        console.log(`Create dataset, result is: ${args}`)
                    })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(`Error in the process: ${err.message}`)
                })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("err", err)
        }
    })
})
```

This is how my Token looks like when I Inspect it

```
{
  "domain": null,
  "_events": {},
  "_eventsCount": 0,
  "transporter": {},
  "credentials": {
    "access_token": "My Token",
    "refresh_token": "my Refresh Token"
  },
  "certificateExpiry": null,
  "refreshTokenPromises": [],
  "_clientId": "my Client Id",
  "_clientSecret": "My client secret",
  "redirectUri": "https://s1dg0yjhih.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stage1/goog/saveToken",
  "eagerRefreshThresholdMillis": 300000
}
```

Comment: What info does [oauth2.tokeninfo](https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo) tell you about the token you are trying to use?

Comment: @David my oAuth2 is a JSON, I added the structure to the question

Answer (score 0):

The JSON object you shared is not an OAuth token, it looks like a OAuth2Client object from @google-auth-library.

An actual OAuth token is simply a string, like "ya29.ABC123ABC123_cG123ABCDETCETCETC".

That "token" is actually an OAuth2Client then you can fetch the token with the `getAccessToken` method.  If it is just a plain JSON object, then you can get the `credentials.access_token` field, is the actual access token.

Note that access tokens expire. `getAccessToken` will get a new one if necessary, but just getting the access_token from the object will not, and can result in 403s after it expires.

Comment: thank you but even why I try clientAuth.getAccessToken() or clientAuth.credentials.access_token both returns ya29. like token, I still get an error message `Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential` (I updated my original code to reflect your code recommendation)

Comment: Can you try [oauth2.tokeninfo](https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo) to see if the token is valid? That will tell us whether we are using a bad token correctly, or using a good token wrongly.

Comment: What values should I put in id_token (maybe the value of _clientId?) and in token_handle. If I only fill access_token ya29xxx I get "Invalid Value" response

Comment: `access_token` is the right field, leave the others blank. If it says Invalid Value, it means there is a problem with the access token. They expire after one hour, so if you are storing an access token and trying to use it an hour+ later, it won't work. `getAccessToken()` is supposed to get a new token if the old one is expired, so I'm surprised you have the same issue using that.

Comment: Not sure what to do now. I did a simple code which call `clientAuth.getAccessToken()`, took the value to oauth2.tokeninfo page and still get an error

Comment: I haven't been able to make @google-cloud/bigquery use a custom OAuth token in my own testing. You might have better with this library: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/. It is not as nice to use as it is autogenerated, and isn't cloud-specific, but it can be a bit more flexible for edge cases.