# Working node example of calling google api with jwt for service-to-service call to raw endpoint?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-bigquery

I've been putzing with trying to call the jobs.Insert bigquery rest api endpoint with node (the jobs.Insert method does not seem to be exposed in the bigquery node library).

I've got the Service-to-Service stuff set up so that I can successfully call the methods that the bigquery node library has (create the json file that has the private key, etc. in it for service-to-service calls).

As far as I can tell, I should be able to do call the rest api directly with a signed jwt as the bearer token without having to go through a two-step OAuth process.

I've got stuff to sign a jwt but still getting authentication errors trying to call the raw api just with curl (as a first step) via something like

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer my_signed_jwt" https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my_project_id/datasets
```

("Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential."

Does anyone have an example of doing this?  Might be missing just a simple thing that a working example would make obvious.

thanks

Comment: Since Google have 2 main client lib its important to understand which one you are using see this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54815207/1031958 on one of the package. If you are using it you need a service account if you want ouath2 you need to use Googleapi.

Comment: Hi @TamirKlein thanks  - I'll go through things again, especially in regards to the different libraries  I'm using a service account, and it looked like it should possible to use a signed jwt as the access_token in that case for bigquery rest endpoints directly without having to first call outh2 endpoint to get access_token.  Maybe my jwt is borked and I need to make sure it has the right stuff in it.   btw, were you able to get things to work with your issue?

Comment: fyi I added a feature request to bigquery to add jobs.insert to the bigquery api (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129168463) and it's already assigned.  Hopefully get some more info about it from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this working example which does

1. Init `query` object
2. Init `oAuth2` object
3. Call `bigQuery.Jobs.insert`

```
if (!global._babelPolyfill) {
    var a = require("babel-polyfill")
}

import {google} from 'googleapis'

let bigQuery = google.bigquery("v2")

describe('Check API', async () => {

    it('Test query', async () => {
        let result = await test('panada')

    })

    async function test(p1) {
        try {
            let query = `SELECT url FROM \`publicdata.samples.github_nested\`
                WHERE repository.owner = 'panada'`

            let auth = getBasicAuthObj()
            auth.setCredentials({
                access_token: "myAccessToken",
                refresh_token: "myRefreshToken"
            })

            let request = {
                "projectId": "myProject",
                auth,
                "resource": {
                    "projectId": "myProject",
                    "configuration": {
                        "query": {
                            query,
                            "useLegacySql": false
                        },
                        "dryRun": false
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log(`query is: ${query}`)

            let result = await callBQ(request) //Check JOB status to make sure it's done
            console.log(`result is: ${JSON.stringify(result.data)}`)

            result.forEach((row, index) => {
                console.log(`row number ${index}, url is: ${row.url}`)
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("err", err)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call BigQuery jobs.insert
     * @param request
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    async function callBQ(request) {
        debugger
        console.log("request", request)
        try {
            let result = await bigQuery.jobs.insert(request, request)//, (err, results) => {
            console.log(`All good.....`)

            return result
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Failed to run query: ${e}`)
        }

    }


    /**
     * Create oAuth object
     * @returns {OAuth2Client}
     */
    function getBasicAuthObj() {
        let clientId = 'myClientId'
        let clientSecret = 'mySecret'
        let redirectUrl = 'url'

        return new google.auth.OAuth2(
            clientId,
            clientSecret,
            redirectUrl
        )
    }
})
```

note: You need to add this line to your `package.json`

```
"googleapis": "34.0.0"
```

Comment: hey thanks @TamirKlein - getting the accesstoken and refresh token are the two main things I was looking to do, which I still haven't clarified (run via node, not in web browser) - Are you suggesting that a callback url is configured in the google console in your example?  I also read (somewhere) that you can use a signed jwt without having to go through that process. I've seen a wide smattering of approaches that have yet to crystallize concretely in my head regarding how to get the appropriate access and refresh tokens for the api calls, which is currently the critical missing piece for me.

Comment: ok - I was able to get the access token and refresh token using jwt stuff via something like this (sorry for formatting, can't enter newlines):  const { JWT } = require('google-auth-library');   var jwt = new JWT(
        jsonObjectFromGoogleKeyEtcFile.client_email,
        null,
        jsonObjectFromGoogleKeyEtcFile.private_key,
        scopes);

    jwt.authorize(function (err, result) {        
        callbackWithErrAndResult(err, result.access_token, result.refresh_token);
    });

Answer (score 0):

ok - the trick as to my original question had to do with getting an access token for use in the api call.

```
const { JWT } = require('google-auth-library');
function getJWTResultWithAccessAndRefreshToken(jsonObjectFromGoogleKeyEtcFile,
                                                callbackWithErrAndResult) {

var scopes = [
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"
            ];

var jwt = new JWT(
    jsonObjectFromGoogleKeyEtcFile.client_email,
    null,
    jsonObjectFromGoogleKeyEtcFile.private_key,
    scopes);

jwt.authorize(function (err, result) {
    callbackWithErrAndResult(err, result.access_token, result.refresh_token);
});
```

}

Here, jsonObjectFromGoogleKeyEtcFile is the json object from the json file you get when you generate "Service account keys"/Credentials in the Google Cloud Platform APIs & Services page.

The access_token generated can be used to make a call like below - which worked - where I used the access_token from the function above, and got the projectId from the project_id property of jsonObjectFromGoogleKeyEtcFile:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer generated_via_jwt_access_token" \                    
          https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/datasets
```

Interestingly, you get a refresh_token, too, but it has value "jwt-placeholder"

Whew.